# ACR122U NFC Reader not Reading ISO14443 Card Properly when Card is ReadOnly

Tags: nfc, apdu, ndef, acr122

I'm using an ACR122U NFC Reader to communicate with a U-Blox Nina-B1 Series module. The NFC component of these modules uses the ISO14443 NFC standard. I am sending the following APDU Command to read the first 255 bytes of data:

```
00 B0 00 01 FF
```

When the module is programmed to be **Read/Write** I get the following result which I can parse and extract the NDEF messages. And when converting to ascii the data is somewhat readable.

```
47 89 01 00 00 00 14 03 54 4D 41 43 02 65 6E 38 36 3A 38 37 3A 34 42 3A 32 30 3A 41 43 3A 43 39 09 01 00 00 00 06 03 54 42 41 54 02 65 6E 39 32 25 49 01 00 00 00 0B 04 54 54 45 4D 50 02 65 6E 32 32 2E 31 30 C2 B0 43 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00
```

However when the module is **Read-only** the following response can't be parsed, and when converting to ascii it's all mumbo-jumbo:

```
04 00 20 81 0A 00 00 15 07 00 00 61 0A 00 00 1F 07 00 00 29 07 00 00 33 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A5 0A 00 00 3D 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 47 07 00 00 51 07 00 00 5B 07 00 00 65 07 00 00 6F 07 00 00 79 07 00 00 83 07 00 00 8D 07 00 00 97 07 00 00 A1 07 00 00 AB 07 00 00 B5 07 00 00 BF 07 00 00 C9 07 00 00 D3 07 00 00 DD 07 00 00 E7 07 00 00 F1 07 00 00 FB 07 00 00 05 08 00 00 0F 08 00 00 19 08 00 00 23 08 00 00 2D 08 00 00 37 08 00 00 41 08 00 00 4B 08 00 00 55 08 00 00 5F 08 00 00 69 08 00 00 73 08 00 00 7D 08 00 00 87 08 00 00 91 08 00 00 9B 08 00 00 A5 08 00 00 AF 08 00 00 B9 08 00 00 C3 08 00 00 CD 08 00 00 D7 08 00 00 E1 08 00 00 EB 08 00 00 F5 08 00 00 FF 08 00 00 09 09 00 00 13 09 00 00 1D 09 00 00 27 09 00 00 31 09 00 00 90 00
```

I don't think this is an authentication issue as the response code (last two bytes) is 0x90 0x00 - *meaning success*.

Furthermore I'm also able to get the NDEF messages when using an NCF reader on my phone when the tag is read-only.

Is this a known issue with the ACR122U Reader or am I not doing something right?

Comment: You have to give more info about your card. Nut just what you think you are reading from the card. ISO14443 is not a card type. It is a protocol standard. For example on the Mifare classic, you can read only 16 bytes. Not 255 bytes. And for only 3 blocks, as then you need another key. On the Ultralight, you get also only 16 bytes on each read request. So the problem could be on the card type, on the read command or even on the ACR command. I have an ACR122U too and I have to send `FF B0 ...` not `00 B0` for example. But without info, nobody can help you.

Comment: @Adriano thanks for your comments. I have updated the question to be more specific about the NCF component I'm dealing with, which is quite different from the typical cards such as Mifare Classic and Ultralight.

Comment: Perfect :) I am trying to understand why you begin with 00. On the acr122 documentation, they write you should begin with the class FF

Comment: The reason for starting with 00 is because when using FF the reader returns an error message "No reponse data" whereas using 00 actually returns data albeit unparsable data.